# Java: Using Swing for programming games

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, 2d-games

I am relatively new to game development. I have been developing games and studying game development for 2-3 months now. I use Java.

I have always used Swing for my graphics (aka, the entire game is displayed on a `JPanel`, using a `Graphics2D` object). I had no trouble with this up until now.

Very recently, I came across a problem in my most recent project. Some method has problems with being called in consistent time intervals (sometimes it runs every 15-16 milliseconds, as it should, and sometimes it starts to run every 3000 (!) milliseconds).

I did some frustrating debugging and some research, and found out that the reason this happens is probably because I'm not handling Swing and threads right.

My entrie game loop runs inside the `run()` method of a thread (which is not the EDT). So I'm modifying Swing elements outside of the EDT all of the time. Obviously this was bound to cause problems.

When I found out this was the problem was, I thought:

"Hey, I'll simply use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` in order to run the gameloop inside the EDT!"

But then I remembered, that just as it's 'forbidden' to **manipulate Swing elements *outside* of the EDT**, it's also problematic to manipulate **non-Swing objects from *inside* the EDT** (*I think... is this correct?*).

If so, then I have no idea how to develop games in Java using Swing **without running into weird problems**.

My question is:

**How can I develop games safely, using Swing? What would be good guidelines for me to be strict about in order to avoid problems involving Swing and threading? Any instructions every game developer who uses Swing should know?**

This is very important for me to understand, since I really want to progress with game development using Java, but if I won't understand this, I'm always going to run into weird problems and won't be able to progress.

Thank you for your help

Comment: From my experience, using a single non-EDT thread works.

Comment: @Darkhogg How come? I though that manipulating for example a JPanel from outside the EDT should cause problems.

Comment: Swing is a widget library with buttons and checkboxes and such... It's really for data + productivity apps. For games, you just want a pixel buffer of OpenGL buffer to draw to. Have you considered lwjgl or jogl? Even for a 2D game?

Comment: in the worst case scenario you can draw gui manually(drawing a rectangle then drawing string on top of it, etc.) But I don't recommend it.

Comment: Just passing 2 years later to say that developing a game in Swing is insane (Or any other "GUI"), when you have multimedia libraries out there specifically for this. The same goes the other way around: Try developing an entire GUI using only a multimedia library...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't modify anything but the graphics drawn on the panel, you *should* be ok most of the time. Just like a single non-EDT thread works *most of the time*. As long as you don't add or remove any gui elements, don't resize anything, don't hide anything etc., Swing won't fiddle with its internal details enough to cause race conditions between your thread and the EDT - most of the time.

Even the case that the user minimizes the panel while your non-EDT-code is drawing on it will not cause crashes - the panel will probably throw away its old graphics context and start working with a new one, but the old context will remain valid until you release it (this is different from C++ where a `delete` invalidates the object immediately, which causes crashes when a different thread still uses a local pointer).

The problem is that if you're using the "i've yet to see a case where it goes wrong, always worked for me" approach, you're relying on undefined behaviour, and your code may start crashing as soon as you update your JVM.

The best thing you can do is set up your GUI on the EDT thread, run your game logic on a different thread, have a timer call `repaint()` on the panel every 20 ms (or whatever you want your frame rate to be). Then, have a class object that holds everything needed to display the current game state. Within a `synchronized` code block, let the panel's `paint()` generate its own copy of the object , and have `paint()` use the copy while the main thread calulates whatever the game needs. The main thread should use the same `synchronized` to write to the class object of course. That way, you get the maximum possible separation between the threads.

Just running your whole game thread on the EDT probably won't do, as anything your game does that might take a while will cause the UI to freeze. And anything that will need a lot of UI resources will affect your game logic.

BTW, are you sure your initial problem (long delays every now and then, but not always) isn't a result of garbage collection? I've seen this several times; if you aren't using the parallel garbage collector, GC might run for several 10's of a second and block everything else.